# Using a self-hosted GitLab install how can I find a projects id to set a CI_PROJECT_ID or for use in the API?

Tags: gitlab

The NPM repos for a project require the `CI_PROJECT_ID` where can I find what that would be for a project without having to echo that in a dummy pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Finding it if you have edit perms

You can find it by going Settings → General, and it should be at the top in a grayed out text box.

[image: General Settings for a project]

## Finding it in the HTML of any page

Go the homepage of your repo, and right click and go view-source,

You should be able to search for `project_id`.

You'll see something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="project_id" id="search_project_id" value="146" class="js-search-project-options" data-project-path="angular-validators" data-name="angular-validators" data-issues-path="/ec-ng-ui/angular-validators/-/issues" data-mr-path="/ec-ng-ui/angular-validators/-/merge_requests" data-issues-disabled="false" />
```

That 146 is the `CI_PROJECT_ID`